# Get IP from URL (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, gethostbyname

How can I get the IP-address from a domain name with the top level domain name?
In this example get the IP of google.com.
And if possible in IPv6 in the correct format.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct hostent* myHostent;
    myHostent = gethostbyname("google.com");
    cout<<myHostent <<"\n";
    //output is a hex code
    cout<<myHostent->h_name<<"\n";
    //output is google.com
    cout<<myHostent->h_aliases;
    //output is a hex code  
}
```

Comment: `h_aliases` is a pointer to pointer of `char` (i.e. points to multiple C-strings). You need to access further one dimension in to see the strings.

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead.  And be prepared to handle the case where the host has more than 1 IP address reported.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostent - note: `gethostbyname` is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: Note that what you get is what your DNS server says, that is your ISP. Sometimes this is not the true IP. Also, the hosts file affects these functions.

Comment: A URL is not uniquely identifiable with a single IP.

Answer (score 2):

The domain's IP addresses (yes plural, there can be more than 1) is in the `hostent::h_addr_list` field, not in the `hostent::h_aliases` field, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
    hostent* myHostent = gethostbyname("google.com");
    if (!myHostent)
    {
        cerr << "gethostbyname() failed" << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << myHostent->h_name << "\n";

        char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; myHostent->h_addr_list[i] != NULL; ++i)
        {
            cout << inet_ntop(myHostent->h_addrtype, myHostent->h_addr_list[i], ip, sizeof(ip)) << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That said, `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, use `getaddrinfo()` instead, eg:

```cpp
void* getSinAddr(addrinfo *addr)
{
    switch (addr->ai_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
            return &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr);

        case AF_INET6:
            return &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(addr->ai_addr)->sin6_addr);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    addrinfo hints = {};
    hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    addrinfo *res;

    int ret = getaddrinfo("google.com", NULL, &hints, &res);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        cerr << "getaddrinfo() failed: " << gai_strerror(ret) << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << res->ai_canonname << "\n";

        char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        for(addrinfo addr = res; addr; addr = addr->ai_next)
        {
            cout << inet_ntop(addr->ai_family, getSinAddr(addr), ip, sizeof(ip)) << "\n";
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assuming a DNS server that does not lie...

Comment: @JesperJuhl sure, but this approach uses the OS's default DNS server, and if that lies then the Internet won't work very well if at all. This approach is "good enough" for more users. If you want to use a *specific* DNS server (that you know doesn't lie), you will have to query it directly yourself.

Comment: plus one for that comment. You are right.